# writing excel formula to compare two sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two excel sheets containing the following data:

**Sheet 1:**

```
MachineName | Department
xxxx        | xxxx
```

**Sheet 2:**

```
MachineName | EID
xxxx        | xxxx
```

I would like to write a formula in excel which retrieves the EID and department of a particular Machine Name pastes the result back into sheet2. The number of rows of the sheets are not fixed.
How do i go about this?

Comment: Sorry it's not clear. Why would you like to paste EID into Sheet2 if it's already there. Do you just want to assign a Department from Sheet1 for each MachineName in Sheet2? If yes, VLOOKUP should do the job.

Comment: with regard to the VLOOKUP syntax, in the column attribute can i specify another column from a different sheet?

Comment: You can. See the answer below. Let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the data in Sheet1 and Sheet2 is in columns A and B, to get Department for the first machine you would do:

```
=VLOOKUP(Sheet2!A2, Sheet1!A:B, 2, 0)
```

and then apply to the rest of machines.

Comment: I am glad I could help :)